# Why doesn't VisualSVN enforce credentials correctly?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, credentials

I have a svn repository that is managed by VisualSVN.

I have created a new group and added two new users to that group. When i attach this group to an existing repository and set the rights to Read/Write, these rights do not work on subdirectories. i have to set the rights on every subdirectory. but even then, the users of this group can only read the repository, they can't write anything to it.

It works for the new users when i create a new repository.

The users use tortoisesvn and get a message like this when they try to write to this repository for example

> https://myserver:8443/svn/subdir/Application/trunk

```
access to /svn/subdir/!svn/act/76a4c6fd-fa15-594a-a419-18493dacaf51' forbidden
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

tortoisesvn can write to the repository as long as the url is in the same case as the server directory.

Example:

```
url:    https://servername/svn/TEST/
dir:    //servername/c$/repo/TEST
rights: read/write
result: read/write works

url:    https://servername/svn/TEST/
dir:    //servername/c$/repo/test
rights: read/write
result: only read works
```